# Given a set with infinitely many elements, could you construct more than one disjoint subsets with infinitely many elements?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am supposed to show that a certain set function is finitely additive (but not countably additive) for subsets in a sigma algebra on an infinite set A. Is it possible to construct many infinite disjoint subsets of A, or does one infinite subset mean all other subsets will be finite for them to be disjoint?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Are the sets $\ H_j=\left\{z\in\mathbb{Z}\left\vert z\equiv 2^{j-1}\pmod {2^j}\right.\right\}\ $ finite or infinite? What is $\ 
H_j\cap H_k\ $ for $\ j\ne k\ $?

Comment: I don't know. I am curious from a "general" perspective i.e. if you have a set that is infinite and a subset that is infinite is it possible to have another (disjoint) subset which is also infinite?

Comment: Moreover, does an infinite subset of an infinite set have to include ALL elements of the infinite set?

Comment: The answer your first questions is yes and the answer to your second is no. If a set is infinite, it can have any number of disjoint infinite subsets. The number of such disjoint infinite subsets can even be infinite, as the example in my answer shows. Each of the subsets  $\ H_j\ $  is infinite, they are disjoint, and there are an infinite number of them.